# Generating tuples from DataFrame row elements

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tuples

I hope this is not me doing something stupid programmatically.

I have a one row Dataframe with numerical Values:

```
df1                          A            B            C          D

 01-02-2003T00:00:00         5.0         7.0          2.0        4.0   ....
```

I want to generate a list of tuples based on the values in the dataframe.  I do the following:

```
my_array = numpy.array(df1)
```

which give me:

```
           0            1            2          3

 0        5.0          7.0          2.0        4.0   ....
```

Then I do:

```
 my_tuple_of_tuples =  tuple((0.5*x, 1.5*x) for x in my_array)
```

I expect this:

```
((2.5,7.5),(3.5,10.5),(1.0,3.0),(2.0,6.0))
```

but I get this:

```
((2.5,3.5,1.0,2.0),(7.5,10.5,3.0,6.0))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just index the first row, then your code should work:

```
tup = tuple((0.5 * x, 1.5 * x) for x in df.values.tolist()[0])
print(tup)
# ((2.5, 7.5), (3.5, 10.5), (1.0, 3.0), (2.0, 6.0))
```

This works because

```
df.values.tolist()[0]
# [5.0, 7.0, 2.0, 4.0]
```

Returns a list of all elements in the first row only. Now, iteration as you do it will work.

---

If you need this to work for multiple rows, you can convert this to a nested loop, or use `chain.from_iterable`.

```
from itertools import chain
tup = tuple(
    (0.5 * x, 1.5 * x) for x in chain.from_iterable(df.values.tolist()))
print(tup)
# ((2.5, 7.5), (3.5, 10.5), (1.0, 3.0), (2.0, 6.0))
```

Comment: Thanks.  I couldn't get this.  What does the `[0]` do?  I can't seem to generate the interim results to better understand (e.g. `tuple((0.5 * x, 1.5 * x) for x in df.values.tolist())` raises an error.  It seems the `[0]` refers to an element in the list.  But I'm not sure why it is needed.  Could you kindly elaborate?

Comment: @Windstorm1981 `df.values.tolist()` returns a list of lists having only 1 sublist. Since you mentioned the data has a single row, I just accessed that with `[0]`.

Comment: I tried with `df.values`  and `df.values.tolist()` prior to posting.  when you say a "list of sublists" is the interim step something like this:  `[[2.5,7.5],[3.5,10.5]...]`?  That can't be because then `[0]` would point to the first sublist.  How am I misunderstanding? Thx.

Comment: @Windstorm1981 You say you have a one row dataframe. So, `df.values.tolist()` returns `[[5.0, 7.0, 2.0, 4.0]]`. I do `df.values.tolist()[0]` to get `[5.0, 7.0, 2.0, 4.0]`. I then iterate over these elements and convert them to tuples as specified in your question. Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes I get it now!  Thanks.